# (Android/Kotlin) OpenStreetMap - Public Transport OSMdroid

Tags: android, kotlin, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I need to make an app in Android Studio using Kotlin that can, among other things, display a map with public transport information.

To get a map i use OSMdroid.

As far as i understood you have to display a map using Mapnik and overlay that map with public transport tiles.

I am able to fully display a normal map but as soon as i try to overlay that map with the public transport information i only get a blank map:

```
//Code to Display a basic Map
        val mapView = binding.mapView
        val ctx = applicationContext
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx))
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
        centerMapOnPosition(51.57412537712895, 7.0285164257552974, 18.5, mapView) // WHS als Beispiel

//Code to overlay public Transport information
        val provider = MapTileProviderBasic(applicationContext)
        provider.tileSource = TileSourceFactory.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT
        val tilesOverlay = TilesOverlay(provider, this.baseContext)
        mapView.overlays.add(tilesOverlay)
```

Using my code i was able to show open sea information using TileSourceFactory.OPEN_SEAMAP in my mind it should work the thame with TileSourceFactory.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT but apparently i do something wrong :c

If i comment the public transport part i get a map that looks like this and is fully functionaly inside my app:

[basic map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qiqR.png)

If i use the public transport part my map is blank:

[blank map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1QxT.png)

Im not sure how exactly the public transport part should look but looking at OpenStreetMap i would expect something like that:

[expected map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NrgO.png)

Comment: The public transport map from Thunderforest requires an API key. Could this be the reason for your empty map? Check your debug log.

Comment: @scai Made an account at thunderforest but i never used an API key before, how would i do that in Android Studio for that specific use case?

Comment: Looks like [`ThunderforestTileSource.java` has a THUNDERFOREST_MAPID](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/74e11fa52010d04e35d04ddb0cd1da1bcc3a75d6/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/ThunderforestTileSource.java#L18C33-L18C52) where you can specify your API key.

Comment: @scai so i signed up for the free version at thunderforest and added my API key to the AndroidManifest.xml but the result in my app is still the same as before.

Comment: Strange. Check your debug log.

Comment: I did and found nothing that is obviously wrong. 

Just to add: Since i added the API key my code from above works like intended if i use TileSourceFactory.OPEN_SEAMAP in the "//Code to overlay public Transport information" part meaning i get a map with an overly of Seamap information.

If i switch to TileSourceFactory.PUBLIC_TRANSPORTATION it stays a blank map :c